# JavaFx передача данных между окнами

Tags: javafx

Каким образом можно обмениваться данными между окнами не по средствам сеттеров?
Я вроде как слышал что для более сложных приложений используется другой метод.

Comment: А каким адресом окна-получателя Вы располагаете? Подходы будут разными, в зависимости от того, имеется ли в наличии java-ссылка на объект окна, или лишь дескриптор окна (hWND), а еще бывают ситуации что в наличии есть только заголовок окна. Также, разные подходы будут, если окна принадлежат разным процессам (например, двум разным JVM), и если окна находятся на разных компьютерах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно привязать значения к Property переменным, привязать их значения к полям и изменять их. (гуглить IntegerProperty с остальными и Bindings) 
twitchViewersLabel.textProperty().bind(InterfacePropertyHelper.twitchViewersProperty

Можно использовать схему с логикой обсервабла, когда изменения в одном месте программы вызывают метод в другом месте.